# Angular 2 is a long time ago

Tags: discussion, tags

The [angular2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular2) tag is somewhat outdated.

I don't think it is a good idea to make a new tag for every version of Angular 2+ but most questions these days are about Angular 6 or 7. (And soon Angular 8).

We need a tag that identify a question as an Angular question and not an [angularjs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) question.

Maybe it is time to rename the Angular2 tag.

I suggest 'Angular' covering everyting else than 'AngularJS'.

There are differences between Angular 2+ versions, but none that would require multiple tags, unless the question actually belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: To put it better for those that don't know the matter : Angular is a rework of AngularJS, as such it is (yet) another framework, while Angular 2-3-4-5-6 is definitively the same framework. Angular 2 is the "first version" of this framework because angularJS was in version 1.x before the rework. So I'm for the rename.

Comment: Absolutely. The current setup doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Sheesh.  Maybe we should just call it [neo-angular]

Comment: @RobertHarvey I’m guessing you’re being facetious but, inverted, this is actually a very good solution: replace the tags for the “old” version with [tag:angularjs-legacy] (± the “js” part), reserve [tag:angular] (or [tag:angular-js]) for versions of the new framework, and burninate [tag:angularjs].